# deploying two projects in tomcat that needs connection to database with different URL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-deployment

In my project a servlet has to connect to database *(derby)*.I build my project into `.war` file.

Now before deploying the project in Tomcat , how do i tell the server the URL of the databsae,JNDI name,driverName etc etc. How do i do this ? I was told to add these into the `context.xml` file. Do i have to create this file myself ? Otherwise there is also a context.xml file in the `conf` directory of tomcat. I have to deploy one more project that also needs to connect to the database but has a different URL. So i think i can't add the details in the `context.xml` file in *conf* directory.

How do i deploy these two projects ? Do i need to make 2 different `context.xml` files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the configuration in a context.xml and put that file in the META-INF folder of your war. See tomcat context documentation on the tomcat website.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using hibernate for persisting data to database then u need to mention the database url, name, password in hibernate.cfg.xml.

If you want to open database connection from Servlet itself.
then refer this http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/databaseconnectionservlet.shtml. i hope it would help you.

Comment: so, what layer are you using for interacting with database?

Comment: A servlet wants to open connection to the database.It is as simple as that.